# How to Update TableViewCells Correctly

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-graphics

What is the correct procedure for having the cells of a TableView show the correct selection state? The table below has these custom indicators I made as a subclass of UIButton. When didSelectRowAtIndexPath is tapped they toggle between lit up and turned off. The dataSource for the tableView is an array of Dictionaries and the dictionaries hold information related to the state of each cell.

The challenge I'm working to solve is that when I scroll through the list incorrect cells are lighting up or turning off which I suspect is a function of cell reuse.

[image]

I have tried putting code in the willDisplayCellForRowAtIndexPath. I think I've solved this problem before but I'm stuck on this one.

Here are the tableView methods

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HourlyWaterCell", for: indexPath) as! HourlyWaterCell
        let dictionary = dataSource[indexPath.row]

        if let startTime = dictionary["startTime"] as! Date? {
            cell.timeLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: startTime)
        }

        return cell
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    var dictionary = dataSource[indexPath.row]

    let buttonState = (tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! HourlyWaterCell).button.completed
    if buttonState == true {
        (tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! HourlyWaterCell).button.completed = false
        cellStates[indexPath.row] = false
        dictionary["selected"] = false
    }
    else {
        (tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! HourlyWaterCell).button.completed = true
        //cellStates[indexPath.row] = true
        dictionary["selected"] = true

        graphView.fill(column: 1)
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let dictionary = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
    if let selectionState = dictionary["selected"] as! Bool? {
        if selectionState == true{
            //cell.button.completed = true
            cell.setSelected(true, animated: true)
        } else {
            //cell.button.completed = false
            cell.setSelected(false, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the custom button class

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class WaterButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = .green
    @IBInspectable var greyColor: UIColor = .gray
    @IBInspectable var completed = false
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 2.0
    let π = CGFloat(M_PI)   //option P for π

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if completed {
            drawStrokedCircle(percentRadius:0.5, color: fillColor, filled: true)
            drawStrokedCircle(percentRadius:0.8, color: fillColor, filled: false)
        } else {
            drawStrokedCircle(percentRadius:0.5, color: greyColor, filled: false)
        }
    }

    func drawStrokedCircle(percentRadius: CGFloat, color: UIColor, filled: Bool) {
        // 1
        let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)

        // 2
        let radius: CGFloat = ((max(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2.0 ) * percentRadius)

        // 3
        //let arcWidth: CGFloat = 76

        // 4
        let startAngle: CGFloat = 0
        let endAngle: CGFloat =  2 * π

        // 5
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                radius: radius,
                                startAngle: startAngle,
                                endAngle: endAngle,
                                clockwise: true)

        // 6
        path.lineWidth = 2.0
        color.setStroke()
        path.stroke()

        if filled {
            fillColor.setFill()
            path.fill()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the exactly same thing, but it is a while ago and I don't have access to the code anymore.

But I did not set the selection in the `willDisplay` method. Instead I set up the selection state in `cellForRowAt`.

Also it might be that I had to implement the bookkeeping if a cell is selected myself inside the table view cells. Hope this helps!

:)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected state (`completed`) of your WaterButton in your delegate then restore the button's state each time the cell that holds your button is dequed (cellForRowAtIndexPath). Observe the change of value of your 'completed' property in your WaterButton.

```
@IBInspectable var completed = false {
    didSet {
        if completed == true {
            drawStrokedCircle(percentRadius:0.5, color: fillColor, filled: true)
            drawStrokedCircle(percentRadius:0.8, color: fillColor, filled: false)
        } else {
            drawStrokedCircle(percentRadius:0.5, color: greyColor, filled: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Restore:
Add an ivar in your tableview's delegate:

`var cellButtonStates : [NSInteger : Bool]?`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HourlyWaterCell", for: indexPath) as! HourlyWaterCell
    let dictionary = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    if let completed = cellButtonStates?[indexPath.row] {
        cell.button.completed = completed
    }
}
```

Obviously you have to update the `cellButtonStates` everytime the user selects a cell:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
/* you can perform extra evaluation to avoid 
iterating to cellButtonStates if not needed */
    for (i,_) in self.cellButtonStates.keys.enumerated() {
        self.cellButtonStates[i] = false
    }
    self.cellButtonStates[indexPath.row] = true
    //call reloadData
}
```

If you want to stick with your code (using isSelected), I suggest you override the isSelected property in your `HourlyWaterCell` like below:

```
class HourlyWaterCell: UITableViewCell {
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        button.completed = isSelected;
    }
}
```

None of the codes above are tested.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately it doesn't work.